# Popup of HealthKit Permission is not appearing in real device and simulator in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, healthkit, health-monitoring

I had used the health [package](https://pub.dev/packages/health) in flutter for steps and running data in android the google fit and physical activity permission are set perfectly but in iOS, it is not asking for health kit permission all other permissions are working perfectly fine here is the code which I had written for permission request

```
  Future<void> requestActivityPermission() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final permissionStatus = await Permission.activityRecognition.request();
      if (permissionStatus.isDenied || permissionStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        _activityPermanenetlyDeniedCase();
        return;
      } else {
        permissionStatus.isGranted;
        fetchTotalStepData();
      }
    } else {
      final permissionStatus = await Permission.activityRecognition.request();
      if (permissionStatus.isDenied || permissionStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        _activityPermanenetlyDeniedCase();
        return;
      } else {
        permissionStatus.isGranted;
        fetchTotalStepData();
      }
    }
  }
```

The requestActivityPermission function is called in the initState Method.

The _activityPermanenetlyDeniedCase function directly opens up, in that function i had a dialog box showing open setting, but in the setting there is no healthkit permission.

I am expecting a popup permission for healthKit

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Can you please share?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which permission you are using in `Info.plist` file under `ios/` directory.

```
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>We will sync your data with the Apple Health app to give you better insights</string>
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string>We will sync your data with the Apple Health app to give you better insights</string>
```

Refer [here](https://pub.dev/packages/health#setup)

Comment: I had done this

Answer (score 0):

Check that the healthkit is activated in both the debug and release tabs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).